# How to reset index of a filtered down dataframe pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good morning,

This is the outpout of my DataFrame:

```
print(df_OIH)

      VolumeOIH
1         84673
79        42034
157       64202
235      260018
313       79126
...         ...
5071      58842
5149     118051
5227      35798
5305      68584
5383      90627

[70 rows x 1 columns]
```

As you can see the row jumps from 1 to 79. I intended to merge this DataFrame with another one but before doing so I want it to be in order so the first row is row #1, the 2nd row would be row#2 etc. I am learning pandas on my own, did not go to school. Is this first column called index and if yes how do I order it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you're showing is instance of a [pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) object, which is basically a dataframe with one column field (and the index). In order to reset the indices, you can use the [`pandas.Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) function with the `drop` parameter set to "*True*":

```
df_OIH['VolumeOIH'].reset_index(drop=True)
```